# java program does not write to file when started via windows console

Tags: java, windows, file-io, console

The title says it all but here are a few more details. I've exported my java program as a runnable jar via eclipse. During the runtime it logs data which should be saved in a text file and in addition to that some infos are printet to the console just for info purposes.

When i start the jar via double-klick on it, it creates the file when it does not exists and does its job propperly but obviously no output to a console because there is none.
To get my console outputs i've tried to launch the jar via the windows console with this command: `java -jar c:\path-to-the-jar\myJar.jar`. It works and prints my outputs to the console but now it does not create the file nor write to an existing one. I've tried to start the console as admin but that was not the solution. I also tried this command: `javaw -jar c:\path-to-the-jar\myJar.jar` but then it does not output to the console BUT it writes to the file...

Do i have to use special startconditions or other commands? I have really no clue where to search and what to google for.

Thanks in advance!
-Phil

Here's my code which handles the output and the file writing

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class DataLog {
    private Path path;
    private LocalDate actualDate;
    private long errorCount = 0;

    DataLog() {
        try
        {
            path = Paths.get("LSV_DataLog_" + LocalDate.now() + ".txt");  //e.g. LSV_DataLog_2019-10-17.txt when its october 17th  2019
            actualDate = LocalDate.now();

            String str = "***" + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate().toString() + " - " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime() + "***"; 

            System.out.println(str);
            Files.write(path, (str + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorCount++;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            errorCount++;
        }
    }

    void addData(long val) {
        try
        {
            if(!actualDate.equals(LocalDate.now())) {
                actualDate = LocalDate.now();
                path = Paths.get("LSV_DataLog_" + LocalDate.now() + ".txt");   //e.g. LSV_DataLog_2019-10-17.txt when its october 17th  2019
            }

            String str = LocalDate.now() + ", " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime() + " Value: " + val;
            System.out.println(str);
            Files.write(path, (str + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorCount++;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            errorCount++;
        }
    }

    void addInfo(String info) {
        try
        {
            if(!actualDate.equals(LocalDate.now())) {
                actualDate = LocalDate.now();
                path = Paths.get("LSV_DataLog_" + LocalDate.now() + ".txt");   //e.g. LSV_DataLog_2019-10-17.txt when its october 17th  2019
            }

            String str = LocalDate.now() + ", " + LocalDateTime.now().toLocalTime() + ", " + info;
            System.out.println(str);
            Files.write(path, (str + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorCount++;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            errorCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code how file writing happens

Comment: "The title says it all but here are a few more details." - it's good you added a few more details because the title says next to nothing ;). In any case, we'd still need to have some more information e.g. how the application is writing to the file, e.g. whether you're rerouting output to stdout to the file or what file path you're using (the file might actually exist just not where you expect it to be).

Comment: Impossible to offer further help without seeing the internals of how the file is written to. Perhaps you are creating the file relative to the current directory? Can you run the `javaw` command by switching to a non-system directory?

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I added the code to my post!

Comment: @adarshr Added my code. Yes the file is created in the directory of the .jar file.

Comment: @Thomas I added my code. The path should be the same as the jar's path. Im not very experienced with file handlings and so on. That is my first rookieish try ;)

Comment: @Michel_T. Hi, i added my code to the post.

Comment: Could you also add to code printing the `path` value - it'll show where the app tries to save a file

Comment: @Michel_T. do you mean the generated string which will be fed into so the method Path.get(...)? That string depends on the actual date like this: `LSV_DataLog_2019-10-17.txt` when its october 17th  2019. Hope thats what you meant.

Comment: just print absolute path to the file: `System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath())` And you'll see where the file was saved to

Answer (score 0):

it would be useful to redirect to this set of  answers about java consol application in eclips, it's not that your question is duplicate but you can have a common concept between the two questions

[Java console program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10344726/5926034)